# RTF color of text in Ruby RTF gem

Tags: ruby, rtf

I have this code to create a RTF document but i can't find how to colorize the text, could someone help me out ?

```
# encoding: utf-8
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

$LOAD_PATH.unshift(File.dirname(__FILE__)+"/../lib/")

require 'rtf'
include RTF
colour = Colour.new(150, 150, 150)

style = CharacterStyle.new
style.bold      = true
style.font_size = 28
style.foreground = colour

document = RTF::Document.new(RTF::Font.new(RTF::Font::ROMAN, 'Times New Roman'))

document.paragraph(style) do |p|
   p << "And there you have it."
end


File.open('my_document.rtf', 'w') {|file| file.write(document.to_rtf)}
```

gives

```
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rtf-0.3.3/lib/rtf/style.rb:124:in `prefix': undefined method `index' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the last example in the RDoc - http://ruby-rtf.rubyforge.org/docs/index.html.

You have created a CharacterStyle and are applying it to a paragraph, which is not allowed. You need to apply the CharacterStyle to the text.

Change your output to be:

```
document.paragraph() do |p|
    p.apply(style) do |t|
        t << "And there you have it."
    end
end
```